# Should I have paid attention to polarity when installing a new light fixture?

Tags: wiring

I just installed a pull chain fixture in a closet.  The light works but I paid no attention to black wire to brass screw or white wire to silver.  Of course when I am tossing the box I see the instructions written on the interior.   Do I have to take it apart and check. Is it a potential problem?

Comment: These are fundamental concepts in house wiring. You probably should do some reading before taking up your next wiring project. It can get dangerous in a hurry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Switching the Neutral OK?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55719/is-switching-the-neutral-ok)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should fix it. If nothing else, if you crossed the wires, the threads of the socket would be hot, even with the switch off. This would give a good chance of shock when changing the bulb if you’re not careful.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will get the ladder!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's essential because you could have wired the fixture as a switched neutral instead of a switched hot... This is deadly! Turning the fixture "off" would not truly switch the hot conductor off and you could get electrocuted with the switch in the "off" position.